# Testing callback method in node and coffescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

I am writing a small program in node and coffeescript using mocha for testing and I am new to all of it. I am using a method to subscribe to a RabbitMQ queue. The callback gives me a json object when there is a message. I also send the queue itself to the callback method handleMessage to be able to use queue.shift.

```
handleMessage: (queue) -> (jsonObject) ->
    if (jsonObject.MyProperty == true)
        #do something
        queue.shift()

queue.subscribe({ack: true, prefetchCount: 1}, handleMessage(queue))
```

I now want to write unit tests for the handleMessage function. First I want to know if queue.shift was called. How do I call handleMessage from within the unit test with the two parameters queue and jsonOject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question about how to call the callback method from the test is to use two parentheses after each other

```
handleMessage(queue)(myJSonObject)
```

But I needed some more lines as well. Here is how my test ended up. (I also put the handling in another file.)

```
myHandler = require '../lib/myhandler'
chai = require 'chai'
expect = chai.expect
should = chai.should()
chai.use(require 'sinon-chai')
{ assert, spy, match, mock, stub } = require 'sinon'

describe 'myHandler.handleMessage', ->
    it 'should shift message', ->
        handler = new myHandler
        myJSonObject = {MyProperty: 'foo'}
        queue = { shift: stub().returns 0 }

        handler.handleMessage(queue)(myJSonObject)
        queue.shift.should.have.been.called
```